# Why is TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I don't know what's wrong with the code.
I haven't tried it yet.
I don't know if the csv file is bad or the custom dataset is bad.

```
model.train()

for i, (img, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    img = img.to(device)
    target = target

    outputs = model(img, target)
    loss = criterion(outputs)  
    loss.backward()  
    losses.append(loss.item())
    optimizer.step()  

for epoch in range(num_epoch):
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epoch))
    print('-' * 10)
```

I don't know what's wrong with this error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/yc/zkgdxm9j5yv1_zlyqb_djtjc0000gn/T/ipykernel_2686/2861585909.py in        <module>
        5     target = target
        6 
  ----> 7     outputs = model(img, target)
        8     loss = criterion(outputs)  
        9     loss.backward()  

  /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in      _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
      725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
      726         else:
  --> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      728         for hook in itertools.chain(
      729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

      /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site- packages/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py in forward(self, images,  targets)
       62             assert targets is not None
       63             for target in targets:
  ---> 64                 boxes = target["boxes"]
       65                 if isinstance(boxes, torch.Tensor):
       66                     if len(boxes.shape) != 2 or boxes.shape[-1] != 4:

       TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model expects `target` to be of type `dict` and has a key named `"boxes"` (among other things). However, it seems like your `target` is a `string`.

Check your `Dataset` and csv.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, check the value of target(labels) and change it to integers.
for example, according to your code

img = img.to(device)
target = int(target)

I didn't run it, i showed it as an example. It might help.